# Why won't imblearn import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, imblearn

I have successfully installed this package in a Jupyter notebook in GCP in the past multiple times.  Now I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 3553, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "/tmp/ipykernel_1/3172500498.py", line 1, in 
> import imblearn
>
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/**init**.py",
> line 52, in 
> from . import (
>
> File
> "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/ensemble/**init**.py",
> line 6, in 
> from ._bagging import BalancedBaggingClassifier
>
> File
> "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/ensemble/_bagging.py",
> line 30, in 
> from ..pipeline import Pipeline
>
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/pipeline.py",
> line 22, in 
> from .utils._metadata_requests import (
>
> File
> "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imblearn/utils/_metadata_requests.py",
> line 1492
> def process_routing(_obj, _method, /, **kwargs):
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have tried restarting the kernel.  I have tried "pip install -U imbalanced-learn" follow by "conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn".  I have tried using an older version of scipy.  I am out of ideas

Edit: It looks like a new version of imblearn was launced yesterday.  Trying %pip install imblearn==0.11.0 does not work because "version does not exist," but installing imbalanced-learn==0.11.0 fixed the problem

Comment: pip install imbalanced-learn==0.11.0 saved me too, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version of imblearn was launched. Trying %pip install imblearn==0.11.0 does not work because "version does not exist," but installing imbalanced-learn==0.11.0 fixed the problem